# Validate partialview with complex model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a timesheet application where I load a PartialView with jQuery. Everything works fine, but I have no idea how to validate the input. I have tried to do it similarly to how I've done it before, but it doesn't work:

```
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++)
       {
           var task = Model.Tasks[i];
    %>
    <tr class="taskrow">
        <td class="customer">
            <%: task.Customer.CustomerName %>
        </td>
        <td class="task">
            <%: task.TaskName %>
        </td>
        <% for (int j = 0; j < task.TimeSegmentList.Count; j++)
           { %>
        <td>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tasks[i].TimeSegmentList[j].Hours, new { @class = "hourInput" })%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tasks[i].TimeSegmentList[j].Hours)%>
        </td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

Although this PartialView is loaded using jQuery, it also contains a submit button which submits to an action method.

Because I'm using the Entity Framework I have read that I need to decorate the model with DataAnnotations like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TimeSegmentMetaData))]
public partial class TimeSegment
{

    public class TimeSegmentMetaData
    {
        [Range(0,24,ErrorMessage = "Must be between 0 and 24 hours")]
        public object Hours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I want to make sure it's a number between 0 and 24 entered here for Hours. (I would also like to make sure it's an int, but I haven't gotten to that yet, need to make validation work at all first)

So this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to do this because I have the complex model with the for loop in the PartialView?

I was also thinking of trying to find some sort of strict jQuery validation (I've seen jQuery plugins exist for this), but I can't figure out how to use jQuery within the PartialView. Because how can I get jQuery to run when the document.ready function is within the main (parent) view? I would need this anyway, because later I want to be able to do things if a user selects an input field...

PS: I'm still rather new to both jQuery and MVC, so I'd really appreciate clear pointers as to what I'm doing wrong... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the type to an Int. Also, you can use foreach instead of the For loop

```
foreach (Task task in task.TimeSegmentList)
```

Comment: Well, the type is object just because it's in the metadata for Entity Framework, in the actual model it's an int. And I can't use the foreach, because the binding in the view with textboxfor needs the for loop.